# matplotlib using Qt4 backend has issue with cached renderer

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4

I was trying to use matplotlib to replot an image in a faster way, so instead of replotting everything, I use set_data method of the AxesImage class as below:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = plt.imshow(np.random.rand(100, 100))

img.set_data(np.random.rand(100, 100))
ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
ax.draw_artist(img)
fig.canvas.update()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

I encountered this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  ...
>       ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 2319, in draw_artist
>       raise AttributeError(msg) AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render

However, if I run the script line by line in python shell (IPython), it works and nothing is wrong. So what is the mystery behind this cached renderer?

EDIT: add a line `fig.canvas.draw()` solves the problem, now the remaining question is why running it line by line in IPython shell does not cause the same error?

Comment: You should also look into blitting.

Comment: @tcaswell according to the post at http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html, blit causes memory leak...

Comment: That is a very old article. It may have been fixed already and if not should be reported upstream as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you figured out, it is necessary to draw the canvas at least once in order to cache the renderer before you can call [`draw_artist`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/axes_api.html?highlight=draw_artist#matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw_artist):

> **`draw_artist(a)`**
>
> This method can only be used after an initial draw which caches the renderer. It is used to efficiently update Axes data (axis ticks, labels, etc are not updated)

---

I'm guessing that in your IPython session you are running matplotlib in [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#controlling-interactive-updating), in which case your initial call to `plt.subplots` will immediately cause the canvas of the new figure to be drawn and the renderer to be cached.

To replicate the `AttributeError` you are seeing in your script, you could turn off interactive mode using `plt.ioff()`:

```
In [1]: plt.ioff()

In [2]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

In [3]: img = plt.imshow(np.random.rand(100, 100))

In [4]: img.set_data(np.random.rand(100, 100))

In [5]: ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b54815e41caa> in <module>()
----> 1 ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)

/home/alistair/.venvs/core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw_artist(self, a)
   2317             msg = ('draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which'
   2318                    ' caches the render')
-> 2319             raise AttributeError(msg)
   2320         a.draw(self._cachedRenderer)
   2321 

AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render
```